# Windows Server 2003 - how to simulate mouse clicks using scripting

Tags: windows, automation, mouse

we have Windows Server 2003 with some native (window-based) applications. We need to repeat several times the same action (writing some numbers in dialogs and clicking some buttons). Is there any application/scripting language which will allow me to simulate those mouse clicking and writing (different) data into window dialogs ? Something which will automatize all those boring actions ... ?

Comment: As an aside I would use this sort of automation only as an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe AutoIt can help you. It provides a scripting language and brings some functions to interact with other processes as a user would do

Comment: +1, beat me by 30 seconds :)

Comment: *And* AutoIt scripts can be compiled into a stand-alone executable for computers without an AutoIt interpreter installed.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) can interact with dialogue windows in the way that you are asking.

Comment: Thank you guys ! AutoIt seems to be the perfect solution :-)